# Can we use one JTable for retrieving data from two different Registration form with mismatch num of columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two forms for EmployeeDetail and DriverDetail for entering data.

Form 1 has 8 columns viz-Date,Name,Accno,ifsc,Amt,Mode,Comp,Salarymonth

Form 2 has 12 columns where 1-7 is same except SalaryMonth column plus 4 more AccHolder,Bank,Remark,Purpose in Form2 i.e DriverDetail

I have created a JFrame class for searching and retrieving data which will be shown below in the `JTable`.
My Coding is finished till designing of 2 forms now retrieving data from DB to JTable is pending .
While coding for JTable the below question arose ?
My Question is:

1. Do I have to design two JTable for retrieving from each form as there is no. of column mismatch?
2. Or Is it possible to use same JTable for both different forms ?
3. When i select EmpDetail then JTable with 8 column must appear and when i select driverDetail then JTable with 12 column must appear

Please suggest what can be done.

[image: Form 1]

[image: Form 2]

[image: Retrieving Data here in JTABLE]

Comment: Please keep your query abstract, clear and to the point. Also provide what you have done till now along with the source code

Comment: Anything can be done.  It just depends on how much effort you want to put into it.  Having said that, I'd create 2 JTables and put them inside 2 JScrollPanes on a CardLayout.  Pick the one you need.

Comment: I'm guessing your frame has multiple text fields or labels or buttons. Why would you not want to create multiple tables?

Comment: @camickr  I added image of two forms and a search table . When i select the EmpForm and go to search.java class  then Jtable with 8 column must come and when i select driverform and go to search.java then Jtable with 12 column must come. How can i get this functionality.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Please provide few more details . I have added images of my forms and search

Comment: This isn't a chat room.  Your last two images look identical.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc sorry for above. Then how do i ask my further doubt to you. SimilarIy to first image there is another and third image is where i want to retrieve as user select the option using same place.I  am trying cardlayout as you said but both Jtable is not overlapping  .

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks ....Almost got it ...by Cardlayout as per my need ...just 10% error .Transition is visible while switching may be cause building in Netbeans. Thanks